# HTML hide full url from URL bar

Tags: javascript, html

Ive seen this on https://forum.en.forgeofempires.com/index.php
 but I can't figure it out.

Basically the FULL URL is http://domain.com/index.php?members/name/

However in the URL bar it only shows http://domain.com/index.php

if I put the curser on the URL bar - it displays the FULL URL. if i take the cursor away, it shrinks back to http://domain.com/index.php

Just wondering

a) does anyone use it - is it useful ? (apart from visual benefit, i dont see other uses)

b) what is this technique is called - so i can look it up & maybe research how to do it (I guess its javascript??)

Comment: The browser does it...Nothing to do with JavaScript

Comment: Nothing you can do to address bar from inside window ... for obvious reasons

Comment: Thanks.I never noticed it before (on any website) except the one above. I've tested it now on others.

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with your page--it is the browser and *only* the browser that can change what the URL is displayed as.

I know for a fact that Safari will do the URL shortening, and you can change it in Safari Preferences (`Command + ,`).

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your browser, not on the website. Safari for example shrinks URLs down to domain (you can change that in preferences).

If you want to make URLs on your website to look nicer, you can use rewrite. Other than that, there is no other way you can change how URL is displayed in your browser.